# Fetching text file(inside a for loop) doesn't work in Python

Tags: python

I was trying to fetch a list of file locations and passing them one by one to open the file.

The following code worked(but outside the for loop)-

```
f = open("E:\\Python\\nltk\\data\\training\\letter\\traindata5-1.txt",'r')
f.read()
```

But when I fetch list of files and apply same logic(on each path), still files are not getting read-

```
fileList = glob.glob("E:\\Python\\nltk\\data\\training\\letter\\*.txt")
for fl in fileList:
    print(fl)
    f1 = open(fl,'r')
    f1.read()
```

WHY?, 
I do not get this behaviour, I'm new to Python, any help would be appreciated

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: No error messages

Comment: What is the content of `fileList`?

Comment: I'm getting the list of files - `['E:\\Python\\nltk\\data\\training\\letter\\train.txt', 'E:\\Python\\nltk\\data\\training\\letter\\traindata2-1.txt', 'E:\\Python\\nltk\\data\\training\\letter\\traindata3-1.txt', 'E:\\Python\\nltk\\data\\training\\letter\\traindata4-1.txt', 'E:\\Python\\nltk\\data\\training\\letter\\traindata5-1.txt'] ` still doesn't work, I do not even get any error messages, must be because of some bad programming practice, well if I get to know it it'll be better.

Comment: Ok, you have no error messages, but what means *files are not getting read-*? Could you please say what is your output?

Comment: It was misunderstanding of the syntax, within `with` statement `f.read()` won't print the content of files on console as it prints content when file is opened with `open` only. That got me confused that the content was not getting fetched. But it is - using `print(f.read())` within `with` prints the content.

Comment: I should have studied about syntax before posting such silly question, sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you get a traceback, an error message, anything? 
Can you provide more context to your code?

This works fine for me:

```
import glob
for txt_file in glob.glob("C:\\temp\\*.txt"):
    print(txt_file)
    with open(txt_file) as f:
        print(f.read())
```

Comment: This approach worked, thanks, but can you explain what mistake I did in my attempt?

Comment: I was missing print( )